# I can't make a CSS class visible by using JavaScript, suggest me an edit

Tags: javascript, css

If I set the searchbox display to block then by using JavaScript I can set it back to none, but I have the following code, but after making display none, I can't set it to block display.

```
#searchbox
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 400;
    float: left;
    display: none;
}

document.getElementById('searchbox').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: whats the `height:400;` all about?

Comment: what kind of element is `#searchbox`? are any of its container elements hidden? are you certain that the javascript code is being executed? have you checked its properties using the browser's dev tools to see what is happening?

Comment: I think that the display needs to be specified inline for the javascript to work - Someone correct me if I'm wrong because I haven't tested it. Also, your javascript needs to be in a `<script>` tag and not right next to the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can then define two JavaScript functions, one to hide and one to show your searchbox, as you said it works fine if you set it to block initially.

Okay, then use the `hide` function to hide your searchbox on pageload event and on onclick event call hide function. It will definitely work.

```
#searchbox
{
    width:50%;
    height:400;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
function hide()
{
    document.getElementById('searchbox').style.display = 'none';
}
function show()
{
    document.getElementById('searchbox').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code is fine, you just need to make sure you're running *after* the element exists. That means in response to a user-generated event, or just using a `script` element further down in the markup than the `#searchbox` element.

For instance, this won't work: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ovuxon/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ovuxon/1/edit)

```
<script>
document.getElementById('searchbox').style.display = 'block';
</script>
<!-- ...other stuff... -->
<div id="searchbox">I'm hidden</div>
```

...because the element doesn't exist as of the call to `document.getElementById`.

But this *does* work: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ovuxon/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ovuxon/2/edit)

```
<div id="searchbox">I'm hidden, but then shown</div>
<!-- ...other stuff... -->
<script>
document.getElementById('searchbox').style.display = 'block';
</script>
```

...because the element *does* exist.

This is one of several reasons for the usual recommendation to put your scripts at the **end** of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag.

More:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google Closure engineers on when DOM elements are ready to be used from script](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)

---

Side note: You have an error in your CSS. `height: 400;` should be `height: 400px;` (you *need* the units). So I suppose if you don't have any content in the div, you might be wondering why you don't see it (and the reason is: because it has no height).

Answer (score 2):

If it is not working then use

```
<script>
document.getElementById('searchbox').style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```

May be it will help you there

Answer (score 0):

It should be set to `.style.display = "inline";` instead of `block`. Block is for `div` and `p` (all the way across). Inline is for `span` and  `input` (not all the way across).